# Publishing Web site without installing Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: iis, reportviewer, publish

I have a web server with ftp access only, and I can't install Microsoft Report Viewer on it.

How do I publish my asp.net app to the IIS **without installing ReportViewer**?

I have copied following dlls to my site bin folder:

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll

Now I am getting error saying:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   The definition of the report 'Reports\QuotationViewReport.rdlc' is invalid.
>   An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I can't even find a dll named `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll` in my local machine.

Is it possible to publish my application without installing ReportViewer ?

Answer (score 20):

Pre-requisite : having Microsoft ReportViewer assemblies installed on your development machine (as [answered by webkite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173241/1178314)).

In Visual Studio, from the `Add Reference` action of your project, choose browse tab and browse to the GAC.
(`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL`).

There, find the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel` assembly folder, choose the version sub folder suitable for your needs, and add the assembly as a local reference.

Then locate the assembly in your references list, and switch its `Local Copy` property to `true`.

For other report viewer assemblies, you should be able to add them directly from the .Net tab in `Add Reference` dialog box. Do not forget to switch the `Local Copy` property to `true` for them too.

With this setup, the ReportViewer assemblies will be copied to your build directory at each build, and you should be able to copy them easily to your target deployment environment.

You may instead try some of the ReportViewer packages than can be found on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=reportviewer). But none of them seem officialy provided by Microsoft.

Comment: This solution saved my day! Thanks a lot. I supposed that with only set as local copy of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll was enough, but was needed to add Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel to my project.

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Very usefull! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Download & Install
Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6442

Answer (score 3):

Add these files to your website's bin folder:

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
>
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
>
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.xml

Comment: that should the top answer

Answer (score 2):

This is now available as a NuGet package:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/

`Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`

Comment: Those NuGet packages does seem official ones, published by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

try C:\Windows\assembly and search for Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel

Or

You can find ReportViewer.exe at the following location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.exe

after you run ReportViewer.exe, the file will copied to the Global Assembly Cache folder on the deployment computer

Comment: c:\windows\assembly dosnt have  Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll.

Comment: By Installing this ReportViewer.exe will fix this. but i cant install anything on hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

hello you can find the dll file open your project
and add refrences and choose browse and select c:/windowse /assemple/GAc_msil
here you find microsoft report viewer folders and select what you want