# Why throws me an error Local Report Services in MVC when is deployed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

Something so rare is happening.

In my rdlc report, I set some textboxes to display as a PDF in the MVC 4 project and if I running it in localhost mode, it works so good.

But if I deployed the solution, throws me the following error.

> Parameter is not valid.  [ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.] 
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc() +1144409
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.LineBreaker.Flow(TextBox
>   textBox, Graphics g, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext,
>   Boolean keepLines, Single& height) +57
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.TextBox.MeasureFullHeight(TextBox
>   textBox, Graphics g, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext,
>   Single& contentHeight) +500
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.TextBox.DetermineVerticalSize(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem, ....
>
> [LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report
>   processing.]
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format,
>   Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode
>   pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback,
>   Warning[]& warnings) +338
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format,
>   Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode ...

[image]

NOTE: I've noticed if a remove those textboxes in my rdlc (I mean removing everthing), generate a blank PDF. So, I realized that the textboxes are the trouble, but I don't know why only when I deployed.

What am I missing?

The code which I'm using is the next one:

```
    public ActionResult SampleReport()
    {
        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
        localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report1.rdlc");

        string reportType = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType
        //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx
        string deviceInfo =
        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        //Render the report
        renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);
        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=NorthWindCustomers." + fileNameExtension);
        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** 
When I start to dig about how to create PDF using Report Services, I only followed these guides:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/11/25/rendering-an-rdlc-directly-to-the-response-stream-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx
- [Publishing Web site without installing Microsoft Report Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165384/publishing-web-site-without-installing-microsoft-report-viewer)

The last one is because, I have to include as Referenced Libraries three of them, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common`, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel` because, when I deploy my solution does not count with these libraries, so I added manually.

And that's it!

Comment: It helps if you include the error *here*, as opposed to a link (that may well rot, in the future). In addition, it would help if you tell us what you've tried and researched so far to solve it.

Comment: @Jeroen I've added more information, if you're think that I'm missing something, please let me know

Comment: I have the same problem deploying to azure websites.. you are also using azure right? I guess the reportviewer has a bad implementation that azure does not accept.

Comment: @Flores I have this working in an Azure Website Application (web job?), but when I move it to an Azure Website, I'm getting the same error as above. Anyone find a solution?

Comment: Our solution was to move away from reportviewer, we now use MvcRazorToPdf